# How do I get along with different cultures in work environment

Tags: professionalism, communication, ethics, cultural-sensitivity

How do I get along (quickly even the minimum) with different cultures in work environment, while communication is a big constraint and colleges are open to differences. The problem is that I find the huge effort of finding shared interests is always on me and this doesn't seem to change in near future (let's say several months)?

The minimum that probably will satisfy me might be that I can be as productive as if I am in my region, but also not to irritate anybody on lunch table with staring eyes on a subject that I don't always have a point on.

So in fact, this minimum is really not about to jump into the other, imitating him, or conceal behind.

Comment: What do you mean by a big constraint? is this a language issue. I never had a problem when I worked for a big Arab consulting engineers in London with a very diverse set of co workers

Comment: ah you are right I wasn't clear, by a big constraint I mean, a very demanding atmosphere for communication, talking on different subjects a lot, and even in a professional space, it can be amusing, and a great opportunity to learn from the other, still, can be frustrating for a newcomer with totally a different culture. It is not a language issue for me.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere let's say, sometime it's frustrating, to listen for long periods, I am just asking for some practical hints to get along with this situation, hopefully to catch difference as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it easiest to connect to people if I listen to them talking about themselves. I look for commonalities we can chat about or look for an opportunity to learn something new. I find it refreshing to talk to someone that doesn't need to have an opinion about everything.

For instance, I tend ask people about their commutes, compare and have a good laugh about how terrible it is. I used to listen in when my colleagues chatted about buying homes way before I thought of buying one.

Comment: nice hints @jcmack I can say in general I should put more patience and feel more OK with being receptive in many situations. It's so right that most rich conversations come with priming common interests.

Answer (score 1):

I would google interests they may have and talk about those topics. Ideally, try to connect with an activity or interest they like that you could live with, even if not something you are thrilled with.